# Spring - Connecting a response from one endpoint to a request to another endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I am facing a certain problem for which i do have some ways to solve, however i am interested if there are more optimal ways to do it. This is a real world problem, but for the purpose of this question i will simplify it.

I have an endpoint called `/initialise-string` which will return a randomly generated string to the front-end. In the front-end, this string might or might not be changed, however it will be sent to another endpoint on the back-end called /`check-if-same-string` which will get the string and it needs to check if it is the same string that was previously returned from `/initialise-string`. So, this would be:

**GET** `www.myapp.com/initialise-string` (front-end gets *asd-123*)

front-end changes string to *asd-555*

**POST** `www.myapp.com/check-if-same-string` (should check if *asd-555* === *asd-123*)

Since this question is for my educational purposes as well, if you can, please provide me answers assuming both if the app is using cookies and if it not using cookies, how you would solve it in each case. Saving to a DB is off limits. Sending both the old and new string back is off limits.

I am looking forward to each answer! Let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To check the String again we need to somehow store the randomly generated string. We can use cookies for this and if we do not want to use DB and we do not want to send the strings to the user then probably we can do it by using some in-memory DB or caching mechanism, so we can store them temporary unless its been verified and also we can apply some time constraint to delete the string from cache after some time. we have to maintain a record to track down the string for the specific request or user to verify it later.